# Failed to resolve the Android SDK path with react-native and expo (missing android folder and no eject available)

Tags: react-native, expo

When using expo for react-native, when I run expo start and "open android", I get the message "Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found:"

I understand there's an answer for this issue when using create-react-native-app. However, using expo omits the android and ios folders from view and the current version doesn't seem to have a eject script.

I tried running "npm run eject" and looked in the app.json for configuration options.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, and it turns out it was an `adb` command that it's attempting to run, which made me think that Android Studio needs installing. https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?package-manager=npm&guide=native&platform=android#android-studio

I'm not sure why it doesn't show this requirement in the documentation (maybe I missed it), but tldr once I installed Android Studio up to point 3 "Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable", it was all smooth sailing!